# Converting Mongodb query to mgo

Tags: go, mongodb-query, mgo

I'm trying to do a query in mongo that basically will be...Get all documents that match this instance Id AND where the status does not equal Deleted or Rejected. I figured out how to do this in mongodb query but I'm having an issue translating it to golang mgo.

This is the mongodb query:

```
db.getCollection('instance_documents').find( {"$and":[
        { "status": {"$nin":['DELETED', "REJECTED"] }},
        {"_id": “instanceID”}
    ]
})
```

This is what I've tried so far in golang, the query does not work properly, it returns nothing:

```
err := appInstanceCollection.Find(bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
                    {"status": bson.M{"$nin": []string{"REJECTED", "DELETED"}}},
                    {"_id": instanceID},
            },
    }).One(&instance)
```

Comment: To be clear, you are checking the error, right? What you're experiencing is an error-free empty result set? If that's the case, I'm worried your problem is somewhere else. Maybe it's the data? How the server is configured? Maybe some sort of data type mismatch? It certainly does not appear to be the mgo query. Does your `instance` struct have it's tags set up properly?

Answer (score 0):

`$and` is unnecessary here. Mongo requires all fields in a query to be true for a document to be returned in the result set. Try setting them all in the same bson.M:

```
err := appInstanceCollection.Find(bson.M{
    "status": bson.M{"$nin": []string{"REJECTED", "DELETED"}},
    "_id": instanceID,
  },
}).One(&instance)
```

As for why your provided `$and` mgo query doesn't work, I'm not sure. It looks fine to me.

Comment: I've tried that, also doesn't seem to work. Originally for status I was only ignoring the deleted ones using $ne, and that worked perfectly fine.